# Influxdb write_points throws AttributeError

Tags: python, influxdb, attributeerror, influxdb-python

I am working on a Python program. I am trying to write a json (see below) into `influxDB` by using `influxdb-python` using the below code -

```
DBclient = client(host, port, user, password, dbname) 
influx_data = json.dumps(write_to_influx_json)
print influx_data
# Writing Data in Influx
DBclient.write_points(influx_data)
```

JSON -

```
[{
    "fields": [{
            "PATH": "/",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "10"
    }, {
            "PATH": "/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
    }, {
            "PATH": "/dev/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
    }, {
            "PATH": "/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "3"
    }, {
            "PATH": "/sys/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
    }, {
            "PATH": "/run/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
    }, {
            "PATH": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
    }],
    "tags": {
            "host_identifier": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "mount_point_percentage"
    },
    "time": "xxxxx",
    "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
}]
```

But i keep getting the below error -

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you're calling the write_points() correctly. The [Docs](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points) for that seem to indicate that you need to provide a lot more info. 
`write_points(points, time_precision=None, database=None, retention_policy=None, tags=None, batch_size=None, protocol=u'json')`
**Parameters:**

*points* (list of dictionaries, each dictionary represents a point) – the list of points to be written in the database

*time_precision* (str) – Either `s`, `m`, `ms` or `u`, defaults to None

*database* (str) – the database to write the points to. Defaults to the client’s current database

*tags* (dict) – a set of key-value pairs associated with each point. Both keys and values must be strings. These are shared tags and will be merged with point-specific tags, defaults to None

*retention_policy* (str) – the retention policy for the points. Defaults to None

*batch_size* (int) – value to write the points in batches instead of all at one time. Useful for when doing data dumps from one database to another or when doing a massive write operation, defaults to None

*protocol* (str) – Protocol for writing data. Either `line` or `json`.

Comment: Tried this - `DBclient.write_points(influx_data, time_precision=None, database=None, retention_policy=None, tags=None, batch_size=None, protocol=u'json')`, still getting the same exception

Comment: In Python, only non-keyword arguments without a default are required. That is only `points` in the above.

Comment: I wonder what time_precision==None means?  Nothing in the referenced docs. Maybe it means infinitely imprecise time?  It sounds like the basis for a Doctor Who episode ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
influx_data = json.dumps(write_to_influx_json)
```

Data needs to be a list of dictionaries, not json.

See [docs](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points).

> write_points(points)
>
> points (list of dictionaries, each dictionary
> represents a point) – the list of points to be written in the database

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code.

First of all, you are not calling `write_points()` correctly (like @Davidgs and @danny said). The [docs](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points) state the following:

> write_points(points)
>
> points (list of dictionaries, each dictionary represents a point) – the list of points to be written in the database

In your code, you are calling `DBclient.write_points(influx_data)`, but the argument `influx_data` is a *string*. The method expects it to be a *list of dictionaries*. This can be solved by sending the JSON data `write_to_influx_json` instead of `influx_data`. So your code should look like this:

```
DBclient.write_points(write_to_influx_json)
```

The second problem is the JSON structure, and to be more specific, the `fields` element. It should be a dictionary, and not a list (like the `tags` element). From what I can see, you are trying to send multiple data points. The data points must be separate dictionaries (as the docs are stating). So your JSON data structure should look like this instead:

```
[
    {
        "fields": {
            "PATH": "/",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "10"
        },
        "tags": {
            "host_identifier": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "mount_point_percentage"
        },
        "time": "xxxxx",
        "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "PATH": "/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
        },
        "tags": {
            "host_identifier": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "mount_point_percentage"
        },
        "time": "xxxxx",
        "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "PATH": "/dev/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
        },
        "tags": {
            "host_identifier": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "mount_point_percentage"
        },
        "time": "xxxxx",
        "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "PATH": "/xxxxxxxxx",
            "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "3"
        },
        "tags": {
            "host_identifier": "xxxxxx",
            "name": "mount_point_percentage"
        },
        "time": "xxxxx",
        "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

and so on.

This error just happened in my code as well! :)